# Linking up multiple Eureka networks through their own respective Zuul gateways

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a group of microservices built using Spring Boot and each registered to a Eureka instance. I also have a Zuul gateway built which does authentication / authorization layer for external requests coming into my microservices. External consumers are not allowed to consume my microservices directly and must go through Zuul. Let's assume that my microservices takes care of a grouped business domain called "Consumer Banking Channel".

Now, somewhere else in my organization there is another grouped domain called "Customer Relationships", where they have built another Eureka-based microservices network and have also configured Zuul to take care of authentication / authorization.

We want to consume each other's exposed API services and want to take advantage of service discovery to do that. However, we do not want to allow direct access to our microservices for security reasons and only want to allow the other group to access our services through our respective Zuuls.

How can this be accomplished?

One possible way that I thought of is to have a Spring Cloud Sidecar to register the other group's Zuul to our Eureka, but that approach does not really scale as the number of different Eureka networks in the organization grows (if we have 10 Eureka networks in the organization, we end up having to run 9 sidecars for each group, totaling up to 90 JVMs just for sidecar alone).

If we move the authentication / authorization layer down to individual microservices and create a big single Eureka network, that would make a big monolith of Zuul with different departments in the organization clashing on how to configure Zuul optimally, not ideal either.